# How can I recreate this bubble wrap effect on my photos?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing, effects

How can I recreate this bubbly effect on photos?

[image: bubble effect]

Answer (score 8):

Find or take a photograph of some bubble wrap.

Open an image you want to use

Copy and paste, or place the bubble wrap image as a new layer

Set the layer blending mode to *Overlay*

[image]

You can also experiment with different layer blending modes, or reduce the layer opacity of the bubble wrap if you want.

Comment: I see the spammy users got burninated. This still provides a good answer to a lazy question, though.

Comment: Now explain *why* someone would do this. 

Comment: @Wolff - well, there's no accounting for taste!